# Can someone help me with how to use chrome-tailor-jetpack?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

this is probably a really noob question, but could someone help me and walk me through using this software? I have a Chrome extension ready, but I just am lost on how to work the software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have 3 links to give you , read the documentation .
https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-tailor/tutorial
https://github.com/jetpack-labs/chrome-tailor
https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2015/08/21/the-future-of-developing-firefox-add-ons/